# Error: Missing required key 'Id' when creating a CloudWatch alarm using 'pod_status_ready' metric

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I am attempting to create an alarm using the 'pod_status_ready' metric. However, when I try to create the alarm, it displays an error as shown below. I am unsure about the actual error in my metrics. I have attached a screenshot of the error, along with the metrics I used to create the alarm.

[image: 1. metrics screenshot]
[image: Acutal error that am seeing while creating alarm]

It should allow me to create the alarm without issue